# Change Field name And Reflacte on wordpress front side

Tags: wordpress

I have One Field And Second Field When i Change Data Field one with one name Immedialtly Change Field name Also On Front side Of my site without Refresh.
Describe On Brief
Like Dev tool When We Change Css and effect Immedialty See On Page.
I Need Plugin Like That.
Thank In Advance. 
And Sorry For Bad English.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Ajax calls here. 
Make a script that hits in every 3 seconds and under that script make a script code on frontend of the website, which will pick current value from database and show changes according to that on frontend.